# In what order does python evaluate this conditional expression?

Tags: python

How does python evaluate this with both an 'and' and an 'or'?

```
lambda x: isinstance(x[1], Decimal) and (str(x[0]), str(x[1])) or (str(x[0]), x[1])
```

Comment: Have you made *any* effort to solve this yourself?

Comment: any resource only gives examples for two, not three at a time.

Comment: is it ((1 and 2) or 3) or (1 and (2 or 3))?

Comment: `and` has higher precedence than `or` so it will be the former

Comment: thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, the precedence for boolean operators is:

- NOT is evaluated before all
- AND is evaluated before OR
- OR

Link: [Operator Precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)